# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{n}e^{-at^{2}}dt$?

Tags: integration

How to evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{n}e^{-at^{2}}dt$ where n is a positive even number and $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-at^{2}}dt=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi /a}$

Comment: Let $x=t^2$, and then use the formula for the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=\sqrt{x}$; then the integral is

$$\frac12 \int_0^{\infty} dx \, x^{(n-1)/2} \, e^{-a x} = \frac{\Gamma \left ( \frac{n+1}{2}\right )}{2 a^{(n+1)/2}}$$

Comment: Thank you. Can we answer this question with just using Leibniz integral rule?

Comment: @esege: please elaborate.

Comment: Well our teacher told us if we constantly take derivative of the first integral with respect to a, we can find some sort of pattern. He didn't mentioned gamma function when he asked this.

Comment: @esege: You can do that, of course, but you will get higher and higher powers of $t$ inside the integral.  In any case, for odd $n$, you get a factorial.

Answer (score 3):

Integrate by parts:

$$I_n = \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{n}e^{-at^{2}}dt
= \frac 1a \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{n-1} (-at e^{-at^{2}}) dt
\\
= \frac 1a \left[-t^{n-1}e^{-at^{2}}\right]_{0}^{\infty}
+ \frac{n-1}a \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{n-2}e^{-at^{2}}dt
=\frac{n-1}a I_{n-2}
$$

You can explicitely compute $I_1$ and you know $I_0$.

$$I_1 = \left[-\frac 1a e^{-at^{2}}\right]_{0}^{\infty}=\frac 1a
\\
I_{2n+1} = \frac{2n(2n-2)\dots 2}{a^n}\frac 1a = \frac{2^nn!}{a^{n+1}}
\\
I_{2n} = \frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)\dots 1}{a^n} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}}
= \frac{(2n)! \sqrt{\pi}}{2^{n+1} n!a^{n+1/2}}
$$